# File naming count on each save in Python

Tags: python, linux, macos, python-2.7, rename

I would like to know how to tell my py script to rename each saved image in loop, instead of overwriting them. As you can see it is saving as image_01.png every 30 seconds.

```
import time
import cv2
import sys
import sched, time

try:
    def DoWork():
            print('Capturing a Picture')
            camera_port = 0
            camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
            time.sleep(0.1)  
            return_value, image = camera.read()
            cv2.imwrite("/Users/pnovak/Desktop/image_01.png", image)
            del(camera)   
            def countdown(t):
                while t:
                    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
                    timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                    sys.stdout.write('Next capture in '+timeformat+'\r')
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    t -= 1
                pass
            countdown(30)
            print
    while True:
            DoWork()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
    print('User CTRL+C')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: just make a counter for it...

Comment: Im not too sure how, Im new to python still, started learning it a few days ago

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import time
import cv2
import sys
import sched, time

try:
    def DoWork(get_name):
            print('Capturing a Picture')
            camera_port = 0
            camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
            time.sleep(0.1)  
            return_value, image = camera.read()
            file_name = "/Users/pnovak/Desktop/image_{0}.png".format(get_name) # new line
            cv2.imwrite(file_name, image)
            del(camera)   
            def countdown(t):
                while t:
                    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
                    timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                    sys.stdout.write('Next capture in '+timeformat+'\r')
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    t -= 1
                pass
            countdown(30)
            print
    counter = 0 # new line
    while True:
            DoWork(counter)
            counter = counter + 1 # new line
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
    print('User CTRL+C')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: @Petr: may you tick me plz? :)

Comment: I already did as soonest I saw this :) its saying, votes with reputation under 15 are recorded. Someone voted my question down, so I cant now :/

Comment: can you tick now?